# Is there a way I can write this code more compact?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, max

is there a way to make this code shorter?
I'm a complete beginner and my task is to read out the company with the most amount of bills out of a list of bills.
My idea is to apply every company to a list, count how often the company is in this list and append this amount to another list.
Then, I find out the indices of the companies with the most amount of bills, append these companies to a new list, and then remove any duplicates from that list so that the company with the most bills is only once in the list.

Thank You!

```
def company_report(bills):
    """puts every company in list, counts how often each company is in list,
    reads the index of company which is the most frequent,
    uses index to read out name of company and how many bills it has."""
    # append all company names from each bill to list
    companies_bills = []
    for bill in bills:
        # use lower() to make sure that there is no uppercase lowercase error
        companies_bills.append(bill[0].lower())
    # count how many times each company is in company list
    dummy = []
    for i in companies_bills:
        dummy.append(companies_bills.count(i))
    # give out indicis of companies with most occurrences
    max_value = max(dummy)
    indices = [index for index, value in enumerate(dummy) if value == max_value]
    comp = []
    # use indicis to append companies with most occurrences to list
    for i in indices:
        comp.append(companies_bills[i])
    # remove duplicates from lists
    final_list = []
    for company in comp:
        if company not in final_list:
            final_list.append(company)
    row = "| {:17} | {:5} |"
    print("\n" + "{:=^29}".format(" Most Popular Company "))
    print(row.format("Company", "Bills"))
    print(row.format("-" * 17, "-" * 5))
    for company in final_list:
        print(row.format(company.title(), max(dummy)))
    print("=" * 29)
    return final_list
```

Comment: I am not sure, but this might be a better fit for Code Review Stack Exchange, make sure however to read all their rules and the formatting they expect in case you go to check there

Comment: You have several lists that can be defined with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries). I would start there.

Comment: Using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) may work as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't try but it should work...

def company_report(bills):
"""puts every company in list, counts how often each company is in list,
reads the index of company which is the most frequent,
uses index to read out name of company and how many bills it has."""

```
# append all company names from each bill to list
companies_bills = [bill.lower() for bill in bills]
# count how many times each company is in company list
dummy = [companies_bills.count(i) for i in companies_bills]

# give out indicis of companies with most occurrences
max_value = max(dummy)

# use indicis to append companies with most occurrences to list
final_list = list(set([companies_bills[i] for i in [index for index, value in enumerate(dummy) if value == max_value]]))

row = "| {:17} | {:5} |"
print("\n" + "{:=^29}".format(" Most Popular Company "))
print(row.format("Company", "Bills"))
print(row.format("-" * 17, "-" * 5))
for company in final_list:
    print(row.format(company.title(), max_value))
print("=" * 29)
return final_list
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine!